# Identifying viewcontrollers presented modally in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 view controllers (`viewcontroller1` and `viewcontroller2`). 
They both have segues presented modally (`vc1segue` and `vc2segue`, respectively) to a third viewcontroller (`viewcontroller3`). In viewcontroller3 I want to be able to identify which viewcontroller/segue was used to present `viewcontroller3` and based on which one do something in `viewcontroller3`.

How would I be able to identify which viewcontroller/segue was used?

Comment: Even with the code edit I still have no clue what you're talking about.

Comment: The best way is to have presenting view controller explicitly set some property as Jelle suggests. But you can also look at `presentingViewController` property (though that does not appear to be set at the time of `viewDidLoad`, but is set by the time of `viewWillAppear`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)` 
to capture the segue preparation and nudge the segue destination in a way that your view controller3 now knows what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

@Jelle's answer is a good way to do this. Here is an alternate way to achieve the same thing in `viewController3's viewWillAppear`:

```
if let viewContr2 = self.presentingViewController as? ViewController2 {
    // ViewController2 was who performed the segue
} else if let viewContr3 = self.presentingViewController as? ViewController3 {
    // ViewController3 was who performed the segue
}
```

`presentingViewController` could be changed for `parentViewController`, depending on your architecture.